# Is it possible to host my website on digitalocean.com without having to push my project on github?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, web-development, python

It's been four days now that i have been trying to host my first web project on digitalocean.com, the project size is about 4GB and I'm having a very difficult time trying to get it on github.com, which I really don't why it keeps throwing this exception "the remote end hung up unexpectedly" when every i try to push the project to my account. i have try some solutions that i fund on stack like git gc --aggressive which it copy all the files without any errors, but it doesn't show in my repo! so i was hoping if there's a way to just upload all the project files straight on digitalocean.com without having to us GitHub. I'm novice when it comes to hosting a website, and just very confuse with the dashboard on digital ocean. Is there any alternative in uploading my project on digital ocean without using GitHub, like uploading from my desktop?

```
this the error i get when i try to push the project to GitHub with the command git push -u origin main .
```

[image]

```
if i user this command (git gc --aggressive) i don't get the error but the file are no where to found in my repo !
```

[image]

```
my dashboard on digitalocean.com
```

[image]

Comment: What hosting plan do you have from DigitalOcean? I wouldn't expect Github to be the ONLY conduit for any of their plans, but different plans have different setup.

Comment: Well at the moment am on their 100 dollar free 60 days trial before i can go on to buy ! also i have tried pushing my project by using git gc --aggressive  GitHub but somehow i  wasn't able to  push file with when  command is done, i don't see the files in my repo and am wondering why am getting that effect ? i used the comment git push -u main but after the files finish writing it throws the error fatal:"the remote end hung up unexpectedly" so i used the git gc --aggressive but when everything is down i don't see any error and also the file don't get to the repo!

Comment: You used that $100 credit to get a VPS?

Comment: I got a droplet i don't know if that's what you mean by getting a VPS? @StephenOstermiller

Comment: I just added the screenshot of my dashboard can you please kindly have a look ?@StephenOstermiller

Comment: " git gc --aggressive which it copy all the files without any errors," `git gc` does not "copy" anything, it cleans your internal repository, and especially with `--aggressive` and recent git versions you shouldn't ever have to run it manually. You may fare better by not just blindly copy and pasting commands from the Internet until one succeeds. You may have otherwise unwanted side effects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A droplet is a virtual machine hosted at Digitalocean. You shouldn't need to push code through Github to connect to it.  Digitalocean has instructions for [ssh access to a droplet](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/how-to/connect-with-ssh/).

With ssh access, you could transfer files directly using `scp` or you could install other software to accept files such as a FTP server.

Comment: Thank  you so much for your solution, I'm currently  trying to upload my files  from the desktop my computer to droplet account with the Putty app using the scp command, but am still having a challenge of getting it to upload the folder where the app is! I used this command  `scp -r C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\dreams root@164.92.212.81:http://164.92.212.81/metadata/v1/` but it tells me there's no such file or directory . what i'm i doing wrong!  this is really has been a great challenge for me for the pass five days! thank you for your patience !

Comment: `http://164.92.212.81/` is very unlikely to be what the directory on your server is named.  If you `ssh` into your server you can use `ls` to see what directories are actually there.  You'll want to put the files into whatever directory is configured as the `DirectoryRoot` in the webserver configuration.

Comment: when i ssh into my server and use the command ls it returned " Snap", so am wondering if that's the directory on my server name and when i use the snap i get this error !ssh: Could not resolve hostname desktop-0e97ont: Temporary failure in name resolution
lost connection

Comment: When you do a `ls` after logging in, it shows you the contents of the directory of the user you logged in is (`root`).  It seems likely that your server is configured to serve out of some other directory entirely.  On Ubuntu that is usually `/var/www`.  You could see what is in that directory using `ls /var/www` and see if your site has been configured there. It is likely that your dashboard on digital ocean tells you what the directory root is.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Ostermiller i was finally able to transfer the app folder by using FileZilla through the ssh protocol SFTP ,your solution had put me on the right path thank you for making time to help me out!  if it's possible could pls vote me up!